# Can not import M2Crypro for Mac OS X 10.10.5

Tags: macos, python-2.7, m2crypto

I was trying to install M2Crypto but `sudo pip install M2Crypto` was giving following error:

```
850 warnings and 3 errors generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of M2Crypto
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-uSFYDz/M2Crypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Nsz5C6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-uSFYDz/M2Crypto
```

Then I installed `sudo pip install M2Crypto==0.21.1`. It didn't give any error but when I tried to import following error is coming:

```
>>> import M2Crypto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import ASN1
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/ASN1.py", line 12, in <module>
    import BIO
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/BIO.py", line 221, in <module>
    class CipherStream(BIO):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/M2Crypto/BIO.py", line 227, in CipherStream
    SALT_LEN = m2.PKCS5_SALT_LEN
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PKCS5_SALT_LEN'
```

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[INSTALL](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) says on the installation on Macs:

> Apple does not provide on more recent versions of Mac OS X (at least
>   certainly since 10.11) any version of OpenSSL, so it is necessary to
>   use brew or similar packaging systems to install third party
>   packages. A Mac OS X users suggested, that this series of commands
>   gave him a working copy of M2Crypto on his system:
>   
>   `$ brew install openssl && brew install swig
>   $ brew --prefix openssl
>   /usr/local/opt/openssl
>   $ LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"
>   CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
>   SWIG_FEATURES="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include" \
>   pip install m2crypto`

I am afraid that completely automagic `pip` installation doesn’t work
ATM. Any merge requests finding existing installation of OpenSSL, which
would be tested on Macs, would be thankfully considered.

Comment: @david-fang could you please accept my answer? Thank you.